# How to reduce default margin of hr tag?

Tags: html, css

I can increase the default margin of a `hr` tag. But I can't reduce the margin of `hr` to zero. All I need is just horizontal line with zero top and bottom margin

```
<p>This is header</p>
<hr class="divider" />
<p>This is content. I just want to reduce the margin of hr tag</p>
```

```css
hr.divider
{ 
   margin-top: 0em;
   margin-bottom: 0em;
   border-width: 2px;
}
```

See also [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/f6hhcdfq/).

Comment: You've already succeeded. It's the `p` elements that have padding and/or margin.

Comment: The P elements are causing the margin in your Fiddle.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it solves your problem. This helps the community be filtering out bad answers.

Comment: our community makes me wait at least 10 minutes to accept the answer :( :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've already succeeded. The `hr` has no margin top or bottom. It's the `p` elements that show `padding` and/or `margin`. Here you can see this in action:

```css
 hr.divider { 
  margin: 0em;
  border-width: 2px;
} 

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

```html
<p>This is header</p>
<hr class="divider" />
<p>This is content. I just want to reduce the margin of hr tag to zero</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably would do much better using semantic tagging and a bit of CSS. `<hr>` are not semantic, they don't carry any meaning and just act on visual aspect of the page. Here's what I would propose using semantic tagging :

**HTML**

```
<h1>This is header</h1>
<p>This is content. I just want to reduce the margin of hr tag</p>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /* This is the line replacing the hr*/
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* This is the space below the line */
    padding-bottom: 15px; /* This is the space between the heading text and the line */
}
```

And [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vz064odd/).

Answer (score 1):

```css
 hr.divider { 
  margin: 0em;
  border-width: 2px;
} 

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

```html
<p>This is header</p>
<hr class="divider" />
<p>This is content. I just want to reduce the margin of hr tag to zero</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hr{
   border:none;
  }
```

to remove the default margin apply the following CSS to your hr element.

Comment: But then it's disappeared now :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
hr {
  margin-top: 0.35em !important;
  margin-bottom: 0.35em !important;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```